# Execute script at crontab

Tags: cron

***General info:***

**SO:**

Ubuntu 18.04

**Script folder:**

```
/home/Emby/Anime/canon_vids
```

**Serie folder:**

```
/home/Emby/Anime/Goblin Slayer
```

I normally execute the script at folder like this:

```
./canon_vids [folder]

./canon_vids Goblin\ Slayer/
```

**Problem:**

I want to execute the script with crontab every 10 minutes as root.

I tried adding like this but isnt working.

```
*/10 * * * * root sh /home/Emby/Anime/canon_vids /home/Emby/Anime/Goblin\ Slayer/
```

Comment: Added how, where? What flavor / version of Unix or Linux are you using? The file format may be slightly different (in particular whether the user field should be present or not)

Comment: Added:

Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*/10 * * * * /home/Emby/Anime/canon_vids /home/Emby/Anime/Goblin\ Slayer/ > /dev/null 2>&1

Its like that u dont need root and i added " > /dev/null 2>&1" to remove mail alerts